# Using assert in pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like to use `assert` in pinescript for bug detection. `assert` statement is available in python and C/C++. I hope there is an easy way to use assert in pinescript.

There's a library available but it looks complicated to me.

https://www.tradingview.com/script/Ddd3hMq8-assert/

I am using pine-script v5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `assert` in `pinescript`.

The library you linked is actually pretty good.

Alternatively, there is `runtime.error` which you can use conditionally.

> When called, causes a runtime error with the error message specified
> in the `message` argument.

Something like this:

```
if barstate.islast and ta.cum(volume) == 0
    runtime.error("No volume is provided by the data vendor.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out PineUnit. It contains test functionality like assertions, units and more as we know from other test libraries

https://www.tradingview.com/script/HIQiZXdL/