# What is wrong with this pinescript assert library function?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

This question is a follow-up question to an earlier question asked.

[Using assert in pinescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74039336/using-assert-in-pinescript)

I tried to write my own library for assert. Here is the code;

```
library(title="TestLibrary", overlay=true)

export assert(bool condition, string error_msg) =>
    if (condition == false)
        runtime.error(error_msg)
```

When I tried to run it with a test code `TestLibrary.assert(false, "OwnLibTestError")`, it did not work. I did not get any error.

The assert implementation looks fine to me. What is wrong with the code?

I am using pine-script v5

Comment: Hi FDL, could you please post your whole code where you're using this library and this assert function too?
This would help me understand what went wrong

Comment: Try to add `plot(close)` in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug, exported function result should be assigned to some variable and used explicitly, so workaround is:

```
//@version=5

library(title="TestLibrary7", overlay=true)

export assert(bool condition, string error_msg) =>
    if (condition == false)
        runtime.error(error_msg)
        false
    else 
        true

plot(close)
```

Script:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

import user/TestLibrary/1 as TestLibrary

x = TestLibrary.assert(false, "OwnLibTestError")

plot(x?1:0)
```